# Getting session info from subdomains to the parent domain [Django]

Tags: django, session, cookies, django-allauth

I have a Django app that is hosted in a `example.com`. Users create groups/team, and each team gets a unique subdomain. Ex: `team1.example.com`

Users log into their team from the team's subdomain. **User A** who is in **team1** will log in from `team1.example.com/login/`. I have set it up this way so that two users logging in from the same browser for different teams (**user A** in `team1.example.com` and **user B** in `team2.example.com`), can maintain two separate sessions.

Now the parent domain is `www.example.com`, and when user visits the parent domain, i want to be able to show the active sessions of all logged in users. Something like:

---

Active sessions:

1. Team 1 (`team1.example.com`)
2. Team 2 (`team2.example.com`)

   ---

I am using Django All-auth for authentication.

**NOTE**: I am aware of the method making `COOKIE_DOMAIN_NAME=".example.com"` and having shared sessions across sub domains. I want to be able to **maintain separate sessions for each sub domain**.

Comment: @Sayse could you please elaborate?

Comment: I am using `django-hosts` for achieving multitenancy (one of the packages mentioned in the grid). The problem i am facing is to be able to identify subdomain login sessions from the parent domain. I know this is achievable as Slack does it. When i log into slack.com, under Your Workspaces they are able to show the active sessions in the subdomains (team1.slack.com etc)

Comment: did you find solution to resolve this problem, I am facing almost the same problem, I want to know if user is authenticated in a site while I am in different one